# PySpark Consulta valores que estan en una tabla y no en otra

Tags: java, pyspark, spark

estoy usando java spark para hacer una consulta de dos dataRowa tengo dos tablas OPERACIONES y OBLIGACIONES relacionadas por el campo G_CONTRACT_ID, estoy intentando sacar las operaciones que no tienen obligaciones relacionadas.

Lo estoy haciendo con un left join, pero me esta devolviendo todas las operaciones, no sé como cambiar la consulta para que me traiga unicamente las operaciones que necesito

**Este es el query que intento simular:**

`SELECT OPER.G_CONTRACT_ID FROM BJP9.T_BJP9_OPERATION OPER LEFT JOIN BJP9.T_BJP9_OBLIGATION OBLI ON OPER.G_CONTRACT_ID=OBLI.G_CONTRACT_ID WHERE OBLI.G_CONTRACT_ID=NULL;`

**Mi código:**

```
 Dataset<Row> datasetUpdated = datasetOperation.alias("OPER")
                .join(datasetObligation.alias("OBLI"),
                        datasetOperation.col(Constants.G_CONTRACT_ID).equalTo(datasetObligation.col(Constants.G_CONTRACT_ID)).
                                and(datasetOperation.col(Constants.G_CONTRACT_ID).isNull()),
                               "left");
```